# Explode text on new empty line in PHP

Tags: php

```
  $MyString=
    "Is post each that just leaf no. He connection interested so we an sympathize advantages. To said is it shed want 

    Tiled say decay spoil now walls meant house. My mr interest thoughts screened of outweigh removing. Evening society musical besides inhabit ye my.

    Oh acceptance apartments up sympathize astonished delightful. Waiting him new lasting towards. Continuing melancholy especially so to. 
    ";
```

### Expected outcome

**Line1:** Is post each that just leaf no. He connection interested so we an sympathize advantages. To said is it shed want

**Line2:** Tiled say decay spoil now walls meant house. My mr interest thoughts screened of outweigh removing. Evening society musical besides inhabit ye my.

**Line3:** Oh acceptance apartments up sympathize astonished delightful. Waiting him new lasting towards. Continuing melancholy especially so to.

I tried to use `preg_split('/^$/m',$mystring)` but did not work

Comment: How did you try to solve your problem? What is your question?

Comment: `array_filter(explode("\n", $myString));`.

Comment: preg_split should work for this.  What's wrong with the output of your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt with preg_split should work pretty well, this will split your string into 3 parts, however, you'll still have extra whitespace.

You can trim all of the elements of the array to resolve that.

```
array_map('trim', preg_split('/^$/m', $MyString));
```